# The impossibility of decomposing the lower shift operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering about the quickest way to prove the following from scratch: the lower shift is not similar to a direct sum of other linear transformations.

Here are the definitions of the terms used in the question. The lower shift is a mapping from $R^n$ to $R^n$ which maps $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n)$ to $(0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$. Given two linear mappings $T_1: U \rightarrow U, ~T_2: V \rightarrow V$ their direct sum is the map from $U \times V~$ to $~U \times V$ which maps $(u,v)$ to $(T_1 u, T_2 v)$.

My current proof of this appeals to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensor by $\mathbb{C}$.  Then the direct sum of two linear transformations has at least two eigenvectors, but the lower shift has only one.  (If you don't want to tensor by $\mathbb{C}$, the corresponding statement over $\mathbb{R}$ is that the direct sum of two linear transformations has at least two one- or two-dimensional invariant subspaces, but the lower shift has only one.)

Comment: Thanks, that is very clean and quick.

Answer (score 3):

The shift is nilpotent.  If it were nontrivially a direct sum, then each of the summands would be nilpotent on spaces of positive dimension.  The kernel of a nilpotent on a nontrivial space is nontrivial, and the kernel of a direct sum is the direct sum of the kernels, so this would imply that the kernel of the shift has dimension at least 2.  But its kernel is 1-dimensional.